# Allow SSI include directive for all HTML pages in htdocs folder using MAMP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mamp, httpd.conf, ssi

I use MAMP to develop sites. I have each site in it's own folder in the htdocs folder. I manage one site that I need to use ssi directives on, because the host doesn't allow php includes.

**I've un-commented these lines in httpd.conf file:**

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

**I added a .htaccess file in the htdocs folder with the following:**

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
```

On the site index page the include works using:

```
<!--#include file="top-nav.shtml" -->
```

But it does not work on files in any sub folder. I get this error:

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the most common reason that SSI still fails following these set up procedures is that that the port (`default 8888`) is not specified when calling the local web page in the browser.

See: http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/first-steps

Comment: https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-Mac/First-Steps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that that using `virtual` rather than `file` works on sub directories. I'm still not sure  if there is any particular reason `file` doesn't work. The question was answered on ***serverfault.com***.

The thread is available here: https://serverfault.com/questions/214096/how-to-enable-ssi-for-all-html-files