# SSI not working on MAMP 2.1.3 on OS X 10.8.3

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, httpd.conf, ssi

I can't seem to get SSI workings on MAMP version 2.1.3 running on OS X 10.8.3
Running on Apache Port 80, PHP version 5.4.10.
In my httpd.conf, I've already included the following settings.

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddType text/html .html
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
Options +Includes
```

But it's still not working, any ideas what else I need to configure?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a relevant question that was raised previously that helped.

Turns out, I had to add a '.htaccess' file to the directory which I was using SSI.

[Allow SSI include directive for all HTML pages in htdocs folder using MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480921/allow-ssi-include-directive-for-all-html-pages-in-htdocs-folder-using-mamp)